# Обработчик кнопки PHP

Tags: php

у меня есть скрипт

```html
echo "<tr>
    <td><input type=\"button\" value=\"Печать\" 
 onclick=\"window.location='index_bronirovanie.php?rooms={$b['rooms']}&beds={$b['beds']}&beds_ext={$b['beds_ext']}&price={$b['price']}&price_max={$b['more']}&position=".urlencode($b['position'])."#form'\" /></td>
    <td height='10'> </td>
</tr>";
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на эту кнопку выполнялся какой-нибудь мой скрипт?

Comment: По нажатию на эту кнопку и так выполняется скрипт `index_bronirovanie.php`, которому по `$_GET` передаются параметры. Если Вы хотите, чтобы ваш скрипт выполнялся, внесите его в `index_bronirovanie.php`. Или же, дайте уточнение по вопросу.

Comment: а как выполнить его не внося в файл index_bronirovanie.php?

Answer (score 2):

Если кнопка находится в составе формы, то на странице с кнопкой можно сделать так:

Дать кнопке атрибут `name='bronirovanie'`

Написать условие:

```
<?
if(isset($_POST['bronirovanie'])){
    #ваш код
}?>
```

Иной вариант будет заключаться в использовании AJAX. Подключите [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) библиотеку, присвоите кнопке идентификатор и по нажатию на кнопку выполните PHP-сценарий, который будет у вас написан в отдельном файле.